# Copy Pasting large Excel files directly into R (with many columns) - "Error in scan"

Tags: r, excel, tidyr, read.table, readr

I can use `read.delim("clipboard")` on *Microsoft Excel* content and insert copied console output into the `text =` argument shown below. This works fine.

```
df1 <- read.table(header = TRUE, text =
"            a           b
1   0.2267953 -0.25450740
2  -1.4967091 -0.90682792
3  -1.3156086 -0.08949872
4   0.2720266 -1.01155805
5   1.1755608 -1.73036765
6   0.5024211 -0.01226299
7   0.2806160  0.33141502
8  -1.8631702  0.35364807
9   0.2669309  0.90964756
10 -1.9147608  0.18394934")
```

If I have too many columns in my *Excel* file things start to break down. I think it's because my console output is portioned into several chunks. If I copy my 'too many columns' console output from `read.delim("clipboard")` and insert it into the `text =` argument below I end up with the following error:

```
df2 <- read.table(header = TRUE, text =
"            a           b           c
1   0.6604331 -0.09190024 -1.30400419
2   0.5114487  0.29496370 -1.25137557
3   0.1955764  0.30972257  0.00478639
4  -1.0400516 -1.08210784 -0.14906742
5  -0.5022574 -0.12988141  0.93325264
6   1.6502558  0.01255227 -0.58192138
7  -0.5359307 -0.92271576  0.43877026
8  -1.1947015 -1.05887833  0.89072608
9   1.0664275 -1.12816603  1.97051795
10  0.2466212 -0.78481492 -0.69115265
             d           e           f
1   0.46968125  1.13310269  0.90007897
2   1.41915478 -0.15813081 -1.07687043
3   2.57197248  0.08487282  0.82166321
4   0.18698150  0.23860853 -0.04076551
5   1.20221764 -0.97671366 -0.13799642
6   0.64680778 -0.77625578 -1.01934201
7   0.25143965 -0.13433564 -2.11476517
8  -0.04562408 -0.41225541 -1.34095833
9   0.77567374 -0.53714819  1.12345455
10 -0.76428423 -0.22667688 -0.18617513
            g          h
1   0.3160803  0.6623033
2   0.6979845  1.3685583
3  -1.5598213 -0.6806526
4  -0.3178346  0.4211778
5   0.8634450 -1.5223605
6   0.4252802  0.1312011
7  -0.6166845  1.6632878
8  -0.2589889 -0.1199479
9  -0.7146200  0.7655468
10 -0.6124751 -0.6891370
")

#> Error in scan(file = file, what = what, sep = sep, quote = quote, dec = dec, : 
#>   line 11 did not have 4 elements
```

Is there a solution to this `'Error in scan'` error? I am aware of the @MilesMcBain excellent [datapasta package](https://github.com/MilesMcBain/datapasta) but want a solution that doesn't require R Studio. Base-R and Tidyverse solutions are happily welcomed.

*Also note that I need to save the data directly in my scripts without importing from `*.csv`, `*.tsv`, or `*.xls` files, hence the motivation of this question.*

Comment: Try using `read.table("clipboard", header = TRUE)` when you copy the larger table from Excel.

Comment: @Mako212 the intent of my question may not be clear, I need to get the data permanently into my R script, without having to refer back to any clipboard or _Excel_ at a future point in time. That's why I'm explicitly defining `df2`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to manage this would be to write the file as a condensed data structure that can easily be reconstructed:

```
library(jsonlite)

toJSON(read.table('clipboard', header = TRUE))
```

The full JSON string will be printed to the console, and you can just copy and paste that into your code, and assign it to an object, let's say `data` -- note, you do need to quote the JSON string:

```
data <- '[{"a":0.0978,"b":0.1704,"c":0.469,"d":0.0919,"e":0.4881,"f":0.414,"g":0.865,"h":0.6461},{"a":0.4975,"b":0.3762,"c":0.5015,"d":0.8096,"e":0.1041,"f":0.8868,"g":0.7983,"h":0.072},{"a":0.2335,"b":0.1997,"c":0.7992,"d":0.3203,"e":0.694,"f":0.2838,"g":0.3469,"h":0.4552},{"a":0.8392,"b":0.2544,"c":0.6384,"d":0.9021,"e":0.7761,"f":0.806,"g":0.431,"h":0.9182},{"a":0.2685,"b":0.2624,"c":0.8339,"d":0.1081,"e":0.3896,"f":0.6784,"g":0.7051,"h":0.2658},{"a":0.4708,"b":0.3424,"c":0.505,"d":0.2119,"e":0.3758,"f":0.1155,"g":0.0585,"h":0.2035},{"a":0.1734,"b":0.9656,"c":0.2278,"d":0.6977,"e":0.7876,"f":0.0204,"g":0.7441,"h":0.626},{"a":0.0751,"b":0.0729,"c":0.3399,"d":0.9851,"e":0.2846,"f":0.0652,"g":0.6614,"h":0.7401},{"a":0.9651,"b":0.9437,"c":0.8807,"d":0.2687,"e":0.6538,"f":0.3907,"g":0.8816,"h":0.5983}]'
```

Which gives you a nice condensed single line that stores the data. Unlike `read.table(text = ...)` this isn't going to have any issues with too many columns, or row/line spacing - at least assuming you're not trying to load a massive data set this way.

You can easily reconstruct the data frame using:

```
fromJSON(data)

       a      b      c      d      e      f      g      h
1 0.0978 0.1704 0.4690 0.0919 0.4881 0.4140 0.8650 0.6461
2 0.4975 0.3762 0.5015 0.8096 0.1041 0.8868 0.7983 0.0720
3 0.2335 0.1997 0.7992 0.3203 0.6940 0.2838 0.3469 0.4552
4 0.8392 0.2544 0.6384 0.9021 0.7761 0.8060 0.4310 0.9182
```

---

If you're committed to staying in the `base` environment, and would rather not load `jsonlite`, you could still do this with `write.csv`, it's just not as clean:

```
write.csv(df2)
```

Prints `df2` out to the console as `.csv`. You can then copy and paste that back into your code (using the first two rows as an example):

```
"","a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h"
"1",0.097767305,0.17043808,0.469039979,0.091881245,0.488090975,0.41400278,0.865041585,0.646119496
"2",0.497482762,0.376181817,0.50152601,0.809582305,0.104101727,0.8868107,0.798329506,0.072007646
```

And then read back in like so -- note again, the output of `write.csv` is wrapped in single quotes:

```
read.csv(text = '"","a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h"
"1",0.097767305,0.17043808,0.469039979,0.091881245,0.488090975,0.41400278,0.865041585,0.646119496
"2",0.497482762,0.376181817,0.50152601,0.809582305,0.104101727,0.8868107,0.798329506,0.072007646', header = T)
```

The downside of using `.csv` is just that it's a messier data structure in your code, but functionally it will still work just as well.

Answer (score 1):

So I ran a similar code and the problem doesn't seem to be how many columns, but if they are broken or not. I ran it twice and when I made my window wider it made R print everything together so it worked. I'll put to links to prints I took to make it clear and the code.

https://puu.sh/CEE3d.png

https://puu.sh/CEE61.png #this is what you want to do, in order to work

```
df2 <- read.table(header = TRUE, text = "
1                a            b            c            d            e            f
2  1  456456456456 456456456456 456456456456 456456456456 456456456456 456456456456
3  2  456456456456 456456456456 456456456456 456456456456 456456456456 456456456456
4  3  456456456456 456456456456 456456456456 456456456456 456456456456 456456456456
5  4  456456456456 456456456456 456456456456 456456456456 456456456456 456456456456
6  5  456456456456 456456456456 456456456456 456456456456 456456456456 456456456456
7  6  456456456456 456456456456 456456456456 456456456456 456456456456 456456456456
8  7  456456456456 456456456456 456456456456 456456456456 456456456456 456456456456
9  8  456456456456 456456456456 456456456456 456456456456 456456456456 456456456456
10 9  456456456456 456456456456 456456456456 456456456456 456456456456 456456456456
11 10 456456456456 456456456456 456456456456 456456456456 456456456456 456456456456
12                                                                   g            h
13                                                     1  456456456456 456456456456
14                                                     2  456456456456 456456456456
15                                                     3  456456456456 456456456456
16                                                     4  456456456456 456456456456
17                                                     5  456456456456 456456456456
18                                                     6  456456456456 456456456456
19                                                     7  456456456456 456456456456
20                                                     8  456456456456 456456456456
21                                                     9  456456456456 456456456456
22                                                     10 456456456456 456456456456
")
#running this got a similar error, but running the next one doesn't

df2 <- read.table(header = TRUE, text = "              a            b            c            d            e            f            g            h
1  456456456456 456456456456 456456456456 456456456456 456456456456 456456456456 456456456456 456456456456
                  2  456456456456 456456456456 456456456456 456456456456 456456456456 456456456456 456456456456 456456456456
                  3  456456456456 456456456456 456456456456 456456456456 456456456456 456456456456 456456456456 456456456456
                  4  456456456456 456456456456 456456456456 456456456456 456456456456 456456456456 456456456456 456456456456
                  5  456456456456 456456456456 456456456456 456456456456 456456456456 456456456456 456456456456 456456456456
                  6  456456456456 456456456456 456456456456 456456456456 456456456456 456456456456 456456456456 456456456456
                  7  456456456456 456456456456 456456456456 456456456456 456456456456 456456456456 456456456456 456456456456
                  8  456456456456 456456456456 456456456456 456456456456 456456456456 456456456456 456456456456 456456456456
                  9  456456456456 456456456456 456456456456 456456456456 456456456456 456456456456 456456456456 456456456456
                  10 456456456456 456456456456 456456456456 456456456456 456456456456 456456456456 456456456456 456456456456")
```

Answer (score 0):

`x <- readClipboard()` to get the clipboard contents

or: copy from excel, and use the `"clipboad"` as input-file....

```
read.table(file = "clipboard", sep = "\t")
```

Comment: Thanks. I now have the data stored in my variable "x". How do I get this "x" data into my `*.R` script so I can reproduce the data at a later point, only utilizing my script, without having to refer back to the Excel file? That's the intent of my question although I may not have been clear enough.

Comment: @JasonHunter `saveRDS()`?